# Haskell manual type inference of this function

Tags: haskell, type-inference

Can someone explain to me how to manually deduce the type of this function `f`?

```
f = map (.) . (:) even
```

I would like to know a step by step solution explaining the things related to precedence and stuff.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1. parse:

```
f = (map (.)) . ((:) even)
```

Step 2. infer some types:

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)
map (.) :: [b -> c] -> [(a -> b) -> (a -> c)]
(:) :: d -> [d] -> [d]
(:) even :: Integral e => [e -> Bool] -> [e -> Bool]
```

Step 3. Derive some equations:

```
x = [e -> Bool] -- the output of (:) even
x = [b -> c] -- the input to map (.)
e = b
c = Bool
```

Step 4. Write down the type of `f`:

```
f :: [(a -> b) -> (a -> c)]
f :: Integral e => [(a -> e) -> (a -> Bool)]
```

Comment: Many thanks @DanRobertson Just one thing, which one was the criteria used to parse the expression that way?

Comment: Every operator has a defined precedence and associativity.

Comment: @DanRobertson Operator precedence and associativity both don't matter here, as there's only one operator, `.`. The rule at play is just "function application binds more tightly than any operator".